# Laravel issue No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: laravel

I'm writing a very common topic, but I am desperate, wasted two days trying to make this work.

I'm on Chrome, trying to make my first Login/Register app and at the time of sending the data to the backend, i get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.133:8100/api/login. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

I am making a POST request from AngularJS like follows:

```
$scope.data = "UserName"; // for example

$scope.register = function() {

      var withAjax = $http.post('http://192.168.1.133/api/register', $scope.data);

      withAjax
        .success(function(answer){
           console.log(answer.message);
      })
        .error(function(answer) {
          console.log("error");
        });
    }
])
```

And the Laravel API backend is simple, just return 'Correct'.

```
public function login (Request $request) {

  $inputArray = $request->all();

  return response()->json(["message" => "Login: All Correct"]);
}
```

In my front-end app I alowed all kind connections with:

```
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<access origin="*"/>
```

In PHP I tried all. Disabled CSFR token for API, and installed properly "*barryvdh/laravel-cors*" and configured cors file like follows:

```
return [
    'supportsCredentials' => false,
    'allowedOrigins' => ['*'],
    'allowedHeaders' => ['*'],
    'allowedMethods' => ['*'],  // ex: ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT',  'DELETE']
    'exposedHeaders' => [],
];
```

When I can make, sending data back and forth easy process, I will care about protection. Now I decided to open 'all' to make it straightforward.

I'm crazy about this, lost two days just trying to solve this.
Any clue would be of help.

Thank you!

Comment: Try to use postman to execute the request and see if you can do it from there.

Comment: Also, please post your routes and where you're placing them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this plugin for Chrome, might help you. [CORS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)